# Is Java volatile keyword necessary if variable gets accessed by only one Thread, but passed through lambda of other Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, thread-safety, volatile

The question refers only to the current provided example (not in general):

Is it safe to omit the the "volatile"-keyword for `mutableVariable` here, or is it absolutely necessary to add it in terms of thread-safety?

The `mutableVariable` gets only accessed in the `Main-Thread`, but because of the lambda-expression, I dont know if it gets "passed" through `Thread-2` and therefore could be cached there, or `Thread-2` sees only a cached value?

Thanks for answers and best reagards.

```java
package test.java;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

import org.junit.Test;

public class A {

    private final BlockingQueue<Runnable> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
    private int mutableVariable = 1; // is "volatile"-keyword absolutely necessary here, or can it be omitted?!


    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {

        // executed in Thread-Main
        final Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            // executed in Thread-2
            this.blockingQueue.add(() -> {
                // executed in Thread-Main
                this.mutableVariable++;
                System.out.println(this.mutableVariable); // should always be 3
            });
        });

        // executed in Thread-Main
        this.mutableVariable = 2;
        thread.start();
        final Runnable r = this.blockingQueue.take();
        r.run();
    }

}
```

Comment: `Is it safe to omit the the "volatile"-keyword for mutableVariable here` In this very specific case, yes.

Comment: TLDR: The fact that the new thread held a reference to the lambda is irrelevant: The only thing that matters is which thread _executed_ the lambda body. Only the main thread does that.

Answer (score 1):

(Caveat: I am not a concurrency expert.)

Given your very specific situation, yes this looks to me to be thread-safe without needing `volatile`. But not recommended.

## Yes, thread-safe

### Objects established before cross-threaded use

I say thread-safe because the thread is in an instance method, so we know the `A` object would be instantiated before that method could be called. Since the `mutableVariable` is initialized in its declaration, we know the object’s existence would have begun before the thread-related method can be called. As the variable is clearly established before the thread, and you change its value only within the thread method, then there is no need for `volatile`.

### Only one background thread

And I say thread-safe because you are starting exactly one thread.

If multiple threads were involved, this code:

```
this.mutableVariable++;
// Something other thread might be incrementing this variable at this point, between these statements. 
System.out.println(this.mutableVariable);
```

… would intermittently fail, with a value printed that was set by some other thread.

## No, not recommended

I say not recommended because there are so many required conditions here, all implicit, that this code in practice would be quite brittle. A programmer later could easily break one of those conditions. For example, being a plain member field on `A`, anyone writing another method would assume they have the right to modify that value. Such a modification would not be safe.

## `AtomicInteger`

Instead, I recommend writing [self-documenting code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code) whenever practical. In particular, using the `Atomic…` classes makes thread-safety concerns quite obvious.

In your case, I would use [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). So this:

```
private int mutableVariable = 1 ;
```

… becomes this:

```
private final AtomicInteger mutableVariableWrapper = new AtomicInteger( 1 ) ;
```

Notice the addition of `final`. This prevents any code from replacing our `AtomicInteger` object with another. Such replacement without a `volatile` would not be thread-safe. In other words, we want `mutableVariableWrapper` itself to *not* be mutable.

The `AtomicInteger` has thread-safe methods for incrementing such as [`incrementAndGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet()). So this:

```
this.mutableVariable++;
System.out.println(this.mutableVariable);
```

… becomes this:

```
int newValue = this. mutableVariableWrapper.incrementAndGet() ;
System.out.println( newValue );
```

Notice in that line above how, with an `AtomicInteger`, we are one step away from our desired value. The `AtomicInteger` is a container, with its `int` payload nested inside. That line above does not directly address that payload value. That line asks the `AtomicInteger` to locate the payload, the `int`, and increment it on our behalf in a thread-safe manner. To emphasize this fact of being one extra step away from the payload, I changed your variable name from `mutableVariable` to `mutableVariableWrapper` in this example code.

If you merely want to see the current value, call [`AtomicInteger#get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#get()).

Comment: great answer. thnx.

Answer (score 1):

The volatile isn't needed in your example.

Lets expand the code a bit:

```
mainThread@this.mutableVariable = 2;
mainThread@thread.start();
// next line we call only the constructor; not the run method. 
thread@this.blockingQueue.add(new SomeRunnable()) 
mainThread@final Runnable r = this.blockingQueue.take();
mainThread@r.run().this.mutableVariable++;
mainThread@r.run().System.out.println(this.mutableVariable);
```

There is only 1 thread accessing the mutableVariable and that is the main thread.

And that means you don't need volatile since a single thread needs to behave as if the instructions are executed sequentially.

[edit]
Solomon Slow already gave this answer in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for volatile keyword in this specific case.

Lets call the main thread T1.

When you call `thread.start()` from T1 the value of `mutableVariable` is 2.

`thread.start()` will execute the `this.blockingQueue.add(...)` in a new thread T2.

`Runnable r` will block until the T2 thread call to `this.blockingQueue.add(...)` is done, and when it is done running your `Runnable` is in the queue.

`r.run()` won't be executed before T2 has finished running it's entire logic which is adding `Runnable` to the queue.

So when `r.run()` is executed:

1. `this.mutableVariable++` will set mutableVariable to 3
2. `System.out.println(this.mutableVariable);` will output 3 as required.

Comment: At the time of initializing the object `final Thread thread = new ...`, it is not possible, that the value of `mutableVaribale` (currently = 1) gets "cached" in `Thread-2` and therefore produces a wrong output of "2"?

Comment: Thread-2 is not created until the call to thread.start, at that point the value of mutableVaribale is already 2. Don’t confuse the creation of the Thread **object** with the actual start of a different OS thread.

Comment: @rranke `mutableVariable` is not accessed at all in `Thread-2` so even if it gets cached (could be as part of some memory page), it does not matter.

Comment: @OrrBenyamini you say, that `mutableVaribale is already 2` before the `Thread-2`  gets created. But would it make any difference, if `mutableVariable` would be mutated to "2" *after* the call to `thread.start`?! that means, if the order would be `thread.start(); this.mutableVariable = 2;` instead of `this.mutableVariable = 2; thread.start(); ` ?!

Comment: The order of these two lines does not matter in this case, as the access to the mutableVariable happens only from the main thread anyway. 

Thread-2 just adds the runnable to the blocking queue